# how to compare two arrays together if they have the same ownerId

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, react-native

[image]how can i compare 2 arrays together if they have the same ownerId.
the fist array is the userUserInfo the second one is the orders array. I want to compare if thet have the same ownerId.
the 2 array are fetching from firebase. 
the newu I wrote is hardly coded if the ownerId is === to the ownerId

### these are the arrays i console.log

```
Array [
  UserInfo {
    "adress": "Flat 76",
    "dateofbirth": "26-09-1995",
    "email": “testt@yahoo.com",
    "id": "-M0s8z5kilepQfGaDarw",
    "namee": “testt”,
    "ownerId": "XS7ARDt5C8hKtQyTSrPh9oLKMUp2",
    "phonenumber": "079112",
  },
 ]
Array [
  Order {
    "date": 2020-02-24T20:46:24.981Z,
    "id": "-M0swr3CHlIJczaLxppg",
    "items": Array [
      Object {
        "productId": "-M0swATocaxb_VboxWrd",
        "productPrice": 10,
        "productTitle": "Water",
        "quantity": 1,
        "sum": 10,
      },
    ],
    "ownerId": "XS7ARDt5C8hKtQyTSrPh9oLKMUp2",
    "productTitle": undefined,
    "totalAmount": 10,
  },
]
```

---

```
const OrderItem = props => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  const [showDetails, setShowDetails] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const orders = useSelector(state => state.orders.orders);

  const userUserInfo = useSelector(state => state.userInfo.userUserInfo)

//const newu = userUserInfo.filter(prod=>prod.ownerId === 'XS7ARDt5C8hKtQyTSrPh9oLKMUp2')



 console.log(userUserInfo)
 console.log(orders)


  return (
    <Card style={styles.orderItem}>
      <View style={styles.summary}>
        <Text style={styles.totalAmount}>£{props.amount}</Text>
        {/* <Text style={styles.totalAmount}>{props.date}</Text> */}
        <Text style={styles.totalAmount}>t{props.items.title}</Text>


      </View>
      <Button
        color={Colors.primary}
        title={showDetails ? 'Hide Details' : 'Show Details'}
        onPress={() => {
          setShowDetails(prevState => !prevState);
        }}
      />
      {showDetails && (
        <View style={styles.detailItems}>
          {props.items.map(cartItem => (
            <CartItem
              key={cartItem.productId}
              quantity={cartItem.quantity}
              amount={cartItem.sum}
              title={cartItem.productTitle}


            />

          ))}
          <FlatList
          data={userUserInfo}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          renderItem={itemData => (
            <Profile

            image={itemData.item.imageUrl}
                    title={itemData.item.namee}
                    price={itemData.item.email}
                    phonenumber={itemData.item.phonenumber}
                    adress={itemData.item.adress}
                    quantityNeeded={itemData.item.dateofbirth}
                    onSelect={() => {
                        selectItemHandler(itemData.item.id, itemData.item.namee);
                    }} >

          </Profile>
           )} />


        </View>
      )}
    </Card>    
  );

};
```

Comment: you need to show those 2 arrays and what you want to achieve in those arrays..

Comment: @SunilLama I added the arrays

Comment: its pretty much value comparison at this point, `UserInfo.ownerId===Order.ownerId`

Comment: @SunilLama thank your for your replay. I want to filter the arrays  to only shows those userUserInfo ho orders. is it write 
const newu = userUserInfo.ownerId === orders.ownerId
this will only return true not the filter array

Comment: Is there ever more than one entry in the `userUserInfo` array? I.e. The first array is a single user and you want to filter all orders matched by owner id from the second? Or are there multiple entries in the first and you want to filter all orders from the second?

Comment: @DrewReese ofcourse there is why do you think it's in an array... Doesn't make sense to be only one object, but let's see what the OP says

Comment: @EugenSunic You know that this is a guarantee? Perhaps it is a poorly designed API response? Perhaps that API happened to only return a single element in array? OP shows only a single entry. How are we to know if that is specifically what is being filtered on or if there are more? This is the point of my question, to get specific and clear details what the OP is working with and what their expected result should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of **filter** and **some** array methods.

Here is an example:

```js
const userInfo = [{
  "ownerId": "XS7ARDt5C8hKtQyTSrPh9oLKMUp2"
}]

const order = [{
  "ownerId": "XS7ARDt5C8hKtQyTSrPh9oLKMUp2",
}]


const res = userInfo.filter(({
  ownerId
}) => order.some(x => x.ownerId === ownerId));
```